# How to use leaky ReLus as the activation function in hidden layers in pylearn2

Tags: machine-learning, theano, conv-neural-network, pylearn

I am using pylearn2 library to design a CNN. I want to use Leaky ReLus as the activation function in one layer. Is there any possible way to do this using pylearn2? Do I have to write a custom function for it or does pylearn2 have inbuilt funtions for tha? If so, how to write a custom code? Please can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ConvElemwise](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/models/mlp.py#L2849) super-class is a generic convolutional elemwise layer. Among its subclasses [ConvRectifiedLinear](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/models/mlp.py#L3305) is a convolutional rectified linear layer that uses [RectifierConvNonlinearity](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/models/mlp.py#L2718) class.

In the `apply()` method:

```
    p = linear_response * (linear_response > 0.) + self.left_slope *\
        linear_response * (linear_response < 0.)
```

As [this](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/) gentle review points out:

> ... Maxout neuron (introduced recently by [Goodfellow et al.](http://www-etud.iro.umontreal.ca/~goodfeli/maxout.html)) that generalizes the ReLU and its leaky version.

Examples are [MaxoutLocalC01B](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/models/maxout.py#L956) or [MaxoutConvC01B](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/models/maxout.py#L515).

The reason for lack of answer in [pylearn2-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pylearn-users/JaSbTVNvrWo) may be that [pylearn2](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/) is mostly written by researches at [LISA lab](https://sites.google.com/a/lisa.iro.umontreal.ca/mila/) and, thus, the threshold for point 13 in [FAQ](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/faq.html) may be high.

Comment: This works. Thanks heaps. Yes it was really hard to find any info regarding this issue on internet

Comment: I had a hard time figuring out the workings of PyLearn2, too. I had to spend some time reading the source code. Pretty enlightening, tho.